# How to display equations results nicely?

Tags: differential-equations, display

I'm very new to Mathematica but i can't seem to find on the internet.
I'm trying to solve a system of equations, the one from the image above:
[image]

Is there any way to display the results in a more understandable and organized way, such as what can be seen on the figure below:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load Mathematica code that can be copied, pasted and executed locally in our own notebook sessions.  Copy directly from your input cell, click the `Edit` button under your post and format as code using the `{  }` icon in the Edit window. Thanks.

Comment: How about adding after //Simplify the following: //TableForm//TraditionalForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solutions are very very long. I do not think there is a way to see them clearly. Even if you convert them to Latex and use display math environments, it will still be a mess.

But you can always do the following

```
eq = {vin*(1/r2 + 1/r1 + 1/(b1*gm1)) - vout*1/r1 - ve1*1/(b1/gm1) == 
   iin, 0 == 
   vin*(1/(b1/gm1) + gm1) - 
    ve1*(1/(b1/gma) + 1/r3 + 1/(b2/gm2) + gm1) + ve2*1/(b2/gm2), 
  0 == ve1*(1/(b2/gm2) + gm2) - ve2*(1/(b2/gm2) + gm2 + 1/r4), 
  0 == vin*(gm1 - 1/r1) + vout*(1/z1 + 1/r1) + ve1*(gm2 - gm1) - 
    ve2*gm2};

sol = Solve[eq, {vin, vout, ve1, ve2}] // FullSimplify
TableForm[Transpose@sol]
```

[image]

This is still hard to read but at least better than before. I cut of the output since it is too long.

I assume what you show at the end there is not related to the solution you obtained, since even with `FullSimplify` the output is not the same.

ps. and next time please post plain text code. Not just image. It was not easy to copy the code from your image.

Comment: Thank you so much! Next time i will upload text code :)